# Can't delete dovecot-managesieved

Tags: debian, package-management, dovecot

When I want to install / delete or whatever a package, I get an error from dovecot-managesieved. So I tried to delete it with this line:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge dovecot-managesieved
reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  dovecot-managesieved dovecot-sieve
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 54 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1,455 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 150840 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing dovecot-managesieved ...
[....] Starting IMAP/POP3 mail server: dovecotError: bind(/var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp) failed: No such file or directory
Error: bind(/var/spool/postfix/private/auth) failed: No such file or directory
Fatal: Failed to start listeners
 failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript dovecot, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing dovecot-managesieved (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing dovecot-sieve ...
[....] Starting IMAP/POP3 mail server: dovecotError: bind(/var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp) failed: No such file or directory
Error: bind(/var/spool/postfix/private/auth) failed: No such file or directory
Fatal: Failed to start listeners
 failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript dovecot, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing dovecot-sieve (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dovecot-managesieved
 dovecot-sieve
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This doesn't work, and I don't know how to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be related to [bug #665487](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=665487). To remove `dovecot-managesieved`, try renaming `/etc/init.d/dovecot` temporarily:

```
sudo mv /etc/init.d/dovecot{,.disabled}
sudo apt-get purge dovecot-managesieved
sudo mv /etc/init.d/dovecot{.disabled,}
```

This should avoid the attempt to restart `dovecot` during the package's removal.